# How to create data for the representative_dataset in TF Lite converter

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert my TF model to TF Lite, so I can use it in a microcontroller.
To be able to convert it, I need a **representative dataset**, which I don't really understand how to correctly create it.

This is my TF model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu", input_dim=5))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy","mean_squared_error"])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=40, verbose=1)
```

The code to convert the model:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
def rep_data_gen():
    yield from X_test.iterrows()
converter.representative_dataset = rep_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)
```

I have tried other ways to create the **rep_data_gen**, but as I don't fully understand it, I had no success. And I had no luck finding a tutorial that helped me understand it better.

This is a snapshot of my data from **X_test**:

```
      Gas_ohm  Humidity  Pressure  Temperature  temp_prof
0   -0.244977  0.876587 -0.726149    -0.550705   1.423705
1    2.914520  0.884880 -0.840744    -0.550705  -1.404848
2    0.506850  0.880733 -0.840744    -0.550705  -0.697710
3   -0.020688  0.884880 -0.840744    -0.550705   0.009429
4   -0.238303  0.880733 -0.840744    -0.550705   0.716567
5   -0.246105  0.880733 -0.840744    -0.550705   1.423705
6    2.928245  0.872440 -0.840744    -0.550705  -1.404848
7    0.485888  0.897321 -0.840744    -0.588416  -0.697710
8   -0.038831  0.913908 -0.840744    -0.626127   0.009429
9   -0.248267  0.918055 -0.840744    -0.626127   0.716567
10  -0.253719  0.909761 -0.955339    -0.588416   1.423705
11   2.843737  0.909761 -0.955339    -0.588416  -1.404848
12   0.470190  0.901468 -0.840744    -0.588416  -0.697710
13  -0.040429  0.901468 -0.840744    -0.588416   0.009429
14  -0.249395  0.901468 -0.840744    -0.588416   0.716567
15  -0.252121  0.901468 -0.840744    -0.550705   1.423705
16   2.856991  0.884880 -0.840744    -0.550705  -1.404848
17   0.477992  0.884880 -0.840744    -0.588416  -0.697710
18  -0.034037  0.897321 -0.840744    -0.550705   0.009429
19  -0.246105  0.897321 -0.840744    -0.550705   0.716567
20  -0.247797  0.893174 -0.840744    -0.550705   1.423705
```

Can someone please help me create/understand the representative dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 good examples of how to create `representative_dataset()` do it:

- Point: *9.1. Quantize model* [github_link](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Train_TFLite2_Object_Detction_Model.ipynb) method `representative_data_gen()` also
  [github_link](https://github.com/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_classification_ptq_tf2.ipynb)
- Point: *Convert to TFLite* https://github.com/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_classification_ptq_tf2.ipynb
- Simplest full example,  without `representative_dataset()` Point: Convert Using TFLite's Converter [C2_W2](https://github.com/https-deeplearning-ai/tensorflow-2-public/blob/main/C2_Device-based-TF-lite/W2/assignment_optional/C2_W2_Assignment_Solution.ipynb) and
  [C2_W3](https://github.com/https-deeplearning-ai/tensorflow-2-public/blob/main/C2_Device-based-TF-lite/W3/assignment_optional/C2_W3_Assignment_Solution.ipynb)

And remember that there are ***4 types of optimization*** in TFlite, and depending on which one you want you have to apply the `representative_dataset()` or not to apply it. Check the types: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization?hl=en-419#quantization

---

In short, ***for your question***, a "Post-training integer quantization" type optimization, you need this `representative_dataset()` (check TODO comments)

```py
#CODE FROM Point: 9.1. Quantize model 
#https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Train_TFLite2_Object_Detction_Model.ipynb 
# Read oficial documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization?hl=en-419#quantization 
import glob
import random


# Get list of all images in train directory
image_path = 'Images_folder'
jpg_file_list = glob.glob(image_path + '/*.jpg')
JPG_file_list = glob.glob(image_path + '/*.JPG')
png_file_list = glob.glob(image_path + '/*.png')
bmp_file_list = glob.glob(image_path + '/*.bmp')

quant_image_list = jpg_file_list + JPG_file_list + png_file_list + bmp_file_list


# A generator that provides a representative dataset
# Code modified from https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_classification_ptq_tf2.ipynb
import tensorflow as tf

# First, get input details for model so we know how to preprocess images
# SAVED_MODEL_PATH_LITE = "model_mobil_v2_C/frozen/model_simple_sigNo_Mdata.tflite"
# interpreter =tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=SAVED_MODEL_PATH_LITE)
# # interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_MODEL) # PATH_TO_MODEL is defined in Step 7 above
# interpreter.allocate_tensors()
# input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
# output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
height = 640 ## TODO:change to your model # input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = 640 ## TODO:change to your model #input_details[0]['shape'][2]


def representative_data_gen():
  dataset_list = quant_image_list
  quant_num = 200  # TODO: Replace 200s with an automatic way of reading network input size 
  for i in range(quant_num):
    pick_me = random.choice(dataset_list)
    image = tf.io.read_file(pick_me)

    if pick_me.endswith('.jpg') or pick_me.endswith('.JPG'):
      image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    elif pick_me.endswith('.png'):
      image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    elif pick_me.endswith('.bmp'):
      image = tf.io.decode_bmp(image, channels=3)

    image = tf.image.resize(image, [width, height])  
    image = tf.cast(image / 255., tf.float32)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    yield [image]

# Finally, we'll initialize the TFLiteConverter module, point it at the TFLite graph we generated in Step 6, and provide it with the representative dataset
# generator function we created in the previous code block. We'll configure the converter to quantize the model's weight values to INT8 format.


# Initialize converter module
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('model_101_C/frozen/saved_model')

# This enables quantization
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# This sets the representative dataset for quantization
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
# This ensures that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# For full integer quantization, though supported types defaults to int8 only, we explicitly declare it for clarity.
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
# These set the input tensors to uint8 and output tensors to float32
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.float32
tflite_model = converter.convert()

TF_LITE_PATH_DATA = "model_101_C/frozen/model_DATA_GEN.tflite"
with open(TF_LITE_PATH_DATA, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
print("Optimized TFlite saved in: "+TF_LITE_PATH_DATA)
```